# Fdisk in a script

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, linux, partition

I had done [a script](https://gist.github.com/josephernest/d0fd00ac5cf1c66b0cc1cf73fef6c85d) whose goal was to build a custom Raspbian distribution for the [SamplerBox  project](http://www.samplerbox.org).

It worked. But now launching this a few months/updates later:

```
fdisk image.img <<EOF
o
n



+64M
a
1
t
6
n




w
EOF
```

makes it fail:

```
Command (m for help): Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0x2bd95ecc.

Command (m for help): Partition type
    p   primary (0 primary, 0 extended, 4 free)    
    e   extended (container for logical partitions) 
Select (default p): 
Using default response p. 
Partition number (1-4, default 1): First sector (2048-2457599, default 2048): Last sector, +sectors or +size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-2457599, default 2457599): 
Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux' and of size 64 MiB. 

Command (m for help): Selected partition 1 
The bootable flag on partition 1 is enabled now. 

Command (m for help): 1: unknown command
```

Any idea what could solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

When you get to the `a` command you only have 1 partition, so fdisk auto selects it since you could not possibly mean anything else:

```
Command (m for help): Selected partition 1 
The bootable flag on partition 1 is enabled now.
```

You are now on the main prompt again so the next char you input `1` is invalid:

```
Command (m for help): 1: unknown command
```

Simply drop the `1` after the `a` and it should work. Alternatively move the `a\n1` to after you have created the second partition.

Note that fdisk is really meant to be an interactive program. `sfdisk` or `parted` are better suited to scripting. Here is what I generally use to set up raspberry pi images:

```
parted --script ${device} mklabel msdos
parted --script ${device} mkpart primary fat32 0% 64M
parted --script ${device} mkpart primary ext4 100M 100%
```

This is much easier to read/understand and less likely to break randomly if you edit it slightly. You may be interested in [this blog post](http://disconnected.systems/raspberry-pi-archlinuxarm-setup/) on the subject of scripting the creation of raspberry pi images.

Comment: Dear G-d.  Second using parted.  Please, for the love of everything holy and good in the world, don't script fdisk.